# How to to use simple method to loop each channel of each pixel in picture?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to print every channel's value of my picture.

Can I do it like this?

Is there any other simple way, such as numpy?

```
import  cv2

img=cv2.imread(r'E:/image/big.jpg')
height,width,_=img.shape
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        for c in range(3):
            print(img[i,j,c])
cv2.imshow('dst',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I don't use python so can't confirm but if that code runs OK then yes this is a sensible way to loop. If your question is really is this code correct I think you might need to do `print(img[i,j,c])`

Comment: What's more do you want?

Comment: I think this loop is too slow, not very good.

Comment: this is simple iteration over elements, you can't make it faster. it might seem slow because of IO overhead

Comment: if you don't want to use 3 loops then just flatten array

Comment: I'd have a look at the [input/output routines](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.io.html) Numpy provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want just simplify 3 for-loops:

```
for e in img.flatten():
    print(e)
```